# The torsion subset of a non-abelian group is not, in general, a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

The torsion subset T of G  is the subset of G consisting of all elements that have finite order.

Let G be a finitely generated group with nontrivial finite derived subgroup.is the torsion subset T form a subgroup of G?

Comment: What is a derived subgroup?

Comment: The derived subgroup of a group is the subgroup generated by all the commutators of the group.

Comment: If the derived subgroup be trivial then G is abelian group and clearly T is a form subgroup of G.

Comment: This is true  for nilpotent group G that  T is a form subgroup of G as well.

Comment: Well it's true in $G/G'$, and $G'$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

It works even more generally: if G' is included in T, then T is a subgroup of G.

And so, if T is not a subgroup of G then G has at least one commutator of infinite order.